# Movilizer - Masterdata referencing modification

Tags: mobile, movilizer

We have a big masterdata pool of customers. With group references.

Customer "key1" is in groups "G2 and G3" (using the  tag).

How can I change this references if for instance now I need customer to be in "G1 and G4" instead of "G2 and G3".

1. Do I have to delete the key, create it again and set the new references to G1 and G4 ... or ....
2. Is there a way to remove a reference and set another one?

Edit
Let's assume this is how I created the masterdata plus references:

```
<masterdataPoolUpdate pool="P1">
  <update key="key1" group="G2"><description>key1Desc</description>
  </update>
  <reference key="key1" group="G3" />
</masterdataPoolUpdate>
```

Comment: As you can see, I created a Movilizer tag and added it to all questions that matched a search on "movilizer" (about 20). At this stage, you don't need (or want) any more tags - there are only 8 hits for "movelet" and they are a subset of "movilizer" hits. When you have a few hundred movilizer posts, you might consider adding more tags to help refine searches.

Comment: Incredible! Thanks a lot for the support ... we will spread the good news now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I managed to figure it ... first I need to remove the original entry in G2 (and also the reference). Then I need to create the entry in G1 or G4 and add a new reference accordingly:

```
<masterdataPoolUpdate pool="P1">
  <delete key="key1" /> <!-- delete key1 and its references --> 
  <update key="key1" group="G1"><description>key1Desc</description></update>
  <reference key="key1" group="G4" />
</masterdataPoolUpdate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: send two new updates to enhance the reference on this groups named G1 and G4. The customer will now have access on this groups.

Step 2: remove the reference for the customer of group G2 and G3 by sending two deletes

Comment: I can not delete key1 in G2 since this is the original entry